# How to make spatio temporal gps clusters in R?

Tags: gps, cluster-computing

I need to identify clusters centroids to visit in the field. the data the I have is Latitude Longitude and Time. I need to identify clusters with the algorithm >= 8 locations within 50 meters within 24 hours. Is there any particular package or function that can help me with this? Thanks